# Typescript Object Returning Array Object Value Error [Angular]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm getting a weird error where when I console log my array value it returns as [object Set]. I'm unsure if this is happening in the component or the service, but I'm not getting the object as values.

This is happening when the deleteRow function is being called from the component and passed to the service.

**view.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
  templateUrl: "viewpage.component.html"
})
export class ViewpageComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  viewData: any;
  viewName: string;
  viewTag: number;
  fetchedData: any;
  dataSource: ViewDataSource;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50];

  defaultSortCol = "1";

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];

  navSub: any;
  primaryTableValue: any;

  constructor(
    private actionService: ActionService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Init the component the first time it is navigated to.
    this.initData();
    // Subscribe to the router, so that any new navigation to this component loads new data.
    this.navSub = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.initData();
      }
    });
  }

  initData() {
    this.viewTag = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("tag");
    this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.actionService);

    // if (this.viewData) {
    //   console.log(this.viewData);
    // }

    // Load the View from the DataSource with default params
    this.dataSource.loadView(this.viewTag, 0, 10, this.defaultSortCol, "asc");

    // Subscribe to the View in the DataSource
    this.dataSource.view.subscribe(x => {
      if (x.ActionName) {
        x.ColumnIds.unshift("9");
        this.viewData = x;
        this.fetchedData = this.viewData.TableData;
        this.primaryTableValue = (this.viewData.ViewData.DbrAction.PrimaryTable);
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // After sorting, jump back to first page of newly sorted data.
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    });
    // Sort changes and pagination events should reload the page.
    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(tap(() => this.loadPage()))
      .subscribe();
  }

  loadPage() {
    this.dataSource.loadView(
      this.viewTag,
      // '',
      this.paginator.pageIndex,
      this.paginator.pageSize,
      this.sort.active,
      this.sort.direction
    );
  }

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.view['source']['value'].TableData;
    return numSelected === numRows.length;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.selection.clear()
      : this.dataSource.view['source']['value'].TableData.forEach((row: TableRow) =>
          this.selection.select(row)
        );
  }

  // Delete row functionality

  deleteRow() {

    this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
      const index: number = this.dataSource.view['source']['value'].TableData.filter (
        (d: TableRow) => d === item
      );
      this.dataSource.view['source']['value'].TableData.splice(index, 1);
      this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.dataSource.view['source']['value'].TableData);
    });
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);
    this.actionService.deleteRow(this.selection, this.primaryTableValue).subscribe(response => {
      console.log("Success!");
    });
  }
```

**view.service.ts**

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ActionService {

  private actionSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentAction = this.actionSource.asObservable();

  private refNumSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentRef = this.refNumSubject.asObservable();

  // private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  // currentPrimaryNumber = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  currentRefNumber: number;

  // This is for saving states of views:
  public stateMap: Map<string, ActionState>;
  public refNumber: number;
  viewData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    // Init the stateMap
    this.stateMap = new Map<string, ActionState>();
    this.refNumber = 0;
  }
  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  // Loads a page of an Action after retrieving data from the API.
  // ##BOOKMARK
  loadPage(actionTag: number, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, sortCol: string, sortDirection: string): Observable<any> {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    return this.http.post<any>('/actions/actionPage/',
      {
        SessionId: user.userEnv.sessionId,
        ActionTag: { value: actionTag },
        SortDirection: sortDirection,
        SortCol: +sortCol,
        PageIndex: pageIndex,
        PageSize: pageSize,
        Filter: ""
      }).pipe(map(actionData => {

        const actionObj = JSON.parse(actionData);

        // Cacheing stuff:
        // this.refNumSubject.next(this.refNumber);
        // let actionState = new ActionState(this.refNumber++, actionTag, pageIndex, pageSize, +sortCol, sortDirection);
        // this.cacheAction(actionState);
        //

        return actionObj;
      }));
  }

    // Delete Row ##TEST

  deleteRow(selection: any, primaryTable: any): Observable<any> {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    const indices = [selection._selection].map((row: { value: any; }) => `${row}`);

    console.log(`Session Id Value in Service: ` + user.userEnv.sessionId);
    console.log(`Primary Table Value in Service: ` + primaryTable);
    console.log(`Row Selection Value in Service: ` + indices);

    return this.http.post<any>('/actions/deleteRow/',
    {
      sessionId: user.userEnv.sessionId,
      table: primaryTable,
      Tag: indices

    }).pipe(map(deleteRowObject => {

      const deleteRowReturn = JSON.parse(deleteRowObject);

      console.log(`test delete ` + deleteRowReturn);

      return deleteRowReturn;
    }));

  }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

'[object object]' because of the + operator, it calls to the toString method of the object

using like this:

```
console.log('scope is ' + scope);
Produced the string scope is [object object]
```

Instead use the console.log() method with commas to be able to print the object

```
console.log('scope is', scope)
```

Comment: for some reason i'm getting the object back as [object set], even using the commas

Comment: I think something is happening in the deleteRow() function call in the component